# SQLite (specifically Android) - is "in" a valid column name?

Tags: android, sqlite

I've spent 10 minutes checking spellings and such but I cannot find an error!

So I am wondering is `in` a valid column name in SQLite? I usually use MariaDB, and provided one escapes/uses statements properly, all is usually well.

```
09-18 03:15:27.892: E/SQLiteLog(30043): (1) near "in": syntax error
09-18 03:15:27.892: E/SQLiteDatabase(30043): Error inserting state=1 time=1378810407
 reading=13964 in=0
09-18 03:15:27.892: E/SQLiteDatabase(30043): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
 near "in": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO 
 Readings(state,time,reading,in) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

Helpful right?

```
-- Describe READINGS
CREATE TABLE "Readings" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "reading" INTEGER,
    "in" INTEGER,
    "time" INTEGER,
    "state" INTEGER
)
```

Use:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("reading", reading.asInt());
values.put("in", in.asInt());
values.put("state",State.OKAY.ordinal());
values.put("time", time.getTimestamp());

return (int) db.insert("Readings", null, values);
```

`in` is actually `0`; I have a whole heap of errors, some with different `in` values. There are no type errors or silenced exceptions.

I didn't expect any errors, and I am not even sure what's wrong.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: @OMGPonies it shouldn't matter, they are escaped, where it puts Readings(state,time,reading,in) VALUES (?,?,?,?), it doesn't actually do that, it's just a textual representation (I would hope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes "in" is a keyword, either SQLite doesn't let you completely bypass SQL, or Android's wrapper is just so thin it doesn't do it for you. Regardless the fix was simple:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("reading", reading.asInt());
    values.put("\"in\"", in.asInt());
    values.put("state",State.OKAY.ordinal());
    values.put("time", time.getTimestamp());

    return (int) db.insert("Readings", null, values);
```

Yes, just put the quotes in there (which I understand is the SQLite way, but it does accept ` (backticks))

Thanks guys.

Comment: Alec, `bi-pass` means passing something twice. I suspect you meant `bypass` :-) In any case, `in` is still a very bad name for a DB column.

Comment: @paxdiablo yes, just wanted to escape the red-squiggle at a very late hour, thanks for that. I also don't agree it's a bad name for a column, in the same way `in` ought not be a bad field name for a member, you are also (usually - I thought) abstracted from SQL, so it becomes handy to think of a DB as providing an array of structures. I digress, but in is a functional name, out can be calculated from the reading and the in quantities in this case, out is presented by the class. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

IN is a keyword. It should work if you quote it:

```
INSERT INTO 
  Readings(state,time,reading,"in") VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

Mid-term, try to get that column name changed.

Answer (score 1):

`in` is actually an SQL keyword, as in:

```
select xyzzy from plugh where grue in ('twisty','passages')
```

Hence, if you want to use it, you probably need to escape it, such as with:

```
select xyzzy from plugh where `in` in ('yes','maybe')
```

How that would translate to the Android method I'm not sure but you wouldn't have these problems if you used substantially more suitable column names. Nudge, nudge, wink, wink.

Sorry, on reflection, that's probably too obtuse. What I mean is: `in` is not really a very descriptive column name. Depending on what it's actually supposed to represent (and the fact I can't immediately tell this is proof positive that it's not descriptive enough), you my want to change it to something like `checkedInTime` or `isInLibrary`.

Comment: That quoting style is non-standard, but it does work in SQLite, too.

Comment: @Thilo it's usually backticks, but when you compile a statement you ought not need it, that's what the ?s do for example, why bother preparing something from data to a structured form, then parse that back to data. I am slightly annoyed that Android's SQLite wrapper is so thin (writing inserts for you) OR that SQLite doesn't support preparing column names (would the ? syntax extend that far?) It's not a dig, just not what I expected.

Comment: @AlecTeal: No, it's not usually backticks. The SQL standard is double quotes for object names and single quotes for literal values. Back ticks is a MySQL thing (which SQLite supports for compatibility). And you cannot use placeholders (?) for schema object names (like columns).